# Integral in physics - how to evaluate it?

Tags: integration, physics

This comes from a physics problem. For $r\le R$, consider
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{R}{2c}} \int_r^R \sqrt{\frac{x}{R-x}} dx$$

The indefinite integral is (by the Wolfram Alpha):
$$\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{x}{x-R}}(\sqrt{x}(x-R)+R\sqrt{R-x}\tan^{-1}{\frac{\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{R-x}}}}{\sqrt{x}}$$
But it did not show the steps. How could I get the indefinite integral?

It's not a homework. I could finish the problem without knowing the method, but I'd like to know how to do this.

Comment: How is it possible the integral's upper limit is the same as the integral's variable, $\;r\;$ ?

Comment: FYI, the formula $$\int_R^rf(r)dr$$ is ill-formed since one cannot use the same symbol for the argument of $f$ and for a bound of the integral. Please rewrite $t$.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot it's not correct mathematically. I did this, to get a t(r) function  as a result.

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, $R=1$.

Complement the argument and get, with $r=1-s=1-t^2$,

$$\int\sqrt{\frac{1-s}{s}}ds=2\int\sqrt{1-t^2}dt.$$

This is the well-known integral for the area of a circle, which is the algebraic sum of a sector and a triangle,

$$\frac12\arcsin t+\frac12 t\sqrt{1-t^2}.$$

[image]

Notice that $\arcsin t=\arctan\dfrac t{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT...try substituting $$x=R\cos^2\theta$$

Comment: I think you're hinting on a question that, as far as I can see, makes no sense...Read the comments below the question.

Comment: the variable has been changed to $x$, sure enough but actually there was nothing wrong with the way the OP set the question in the first place. This is standard notation in mechanics and physics

Comment: Even if that is correct, this is a **mathematics** site and as such the question should be written in a way it makes sense in mathematics or, *at the very least*, add an explanation about the way notation's being used. So I'd say the question was very wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: successively substitute $y = R - x$ followed by $\frac Ry = \sec^2 \theta$. The final integral is easy to evaluate using a double angle cosine identity.